# Importing python file into my pycharm that is in the same directory

Tags: python, import, pycharm

Im trying to import a python file into my pycharm program.

The file is in the exact same folder as my pycharm project is.
I tried to use :

```
open("happy_histogram.py","r",encoding="utf-8")
```

but it fails to work.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

What are you importing the file for? If you're trying to use some functions and other variables in happy_histogram.py you maybe be better importing it using

`from happy_histogram import *`

But to make your code work, I was able to open a file by taking out the encoding. `open("happy_histogram.py", "r")`  hope that helps.